# nodejs request target url

Tags: node.js, http-headers, request

i want to get the result for this target url.  by browser the result is ok, but this nodejs code don't work. i wish someone can help me,thanks a lot.

```
var request = require('request');
request = request.defaults({
    headers: {
            Accept: '*/*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
});

request('http://xueqiu.com/stock/search.json?code=alibaba', function(error, res, body) {
    if (error) {
            console.log(error);
    } else {
            console.log(res);
    }
});
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: just change the else part to `console.log(JSON.parse(body));` and it should print the JSON response.

Comment: thank you ,guys. i have resolved this issue. when we request the url , it doesn't work. because this site set a rule that when you call its api, your request should be assigned some cookie info. and you can get the cookie by request its homepage.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the cookie from xueqiu.com homepage before hitting this URL. Cookies can be reused using a jar

```
var request = require('request');
request = request.defaults({
  headers: {'Accept': '*/*',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
  jar: true    // reuse cookies across requests
});

request('http://xueqiu.com', function() {
  request('http://xueqiu.com/stock/search.json?code=alibaba', function(error, res, body) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log(res);
    }
  });
});
```